# Simba Phoenix ODBC driver Kerberos

Tags: odbc, kerberos, apache-phoenix, simba

I have configured Phoenix Query server for HBase datasource with kerberos authentication.

When trying to connect with query server using Simba Phoenix ODBC driver getting HTTP Request/Response error with Authentication type as kerberos.

**Error Msg: [Simba][Phoenix] (40) Error with HTTP request, response code: 404**

Also simba doesn't have any input fields enabled for Kerberos authentication, does it requires any other configuration step in client machine to connect with kerberized query server.

Comment: Which version of the driver? Running on Windows, Linux, MacOS? Do you have a valid Kerberos ticket available before connecting?

Comment: The Simba web site is a real pain but it explicitly states that, **if you have Kerberos credentials available at connect time**, they will be used automatically. On Windows, there are 3 different sections for 3 different flavors of Kerberos -- Active Directory, Azure, and Linux-style MIT Kerberos _(for V1.0.7 at the time of writing)_.

Comment: Hi @SamsonScharfrichter Using Simba Phoenix 1.0 version running on Windows machine. Also i have valid kerberos tickets through which i can able to establish connection using sqlline-thin and it works fine for me.